AH00035: access to /path/ denied because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
I am trying to deploy a flask app locally.
Now I am stuck at some permission error.
AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/media/rene/mybook') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
Tech:
Ubuntu 22 LTS
Apache2
PHPmyadmin
Flask app on external hdd
apache2.conf
<Directory "/media/rene/mybook/VSCode/Webvideo">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

thehub.conf (My Vhost file)
<VirtualHost *:5000>
        ServerName  localhost
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /media/rene/mybook/VSCode/Webvideo

        WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp threads=5
        WSGIScriptAlias / /media/rene/mybook/VSCode/Webvideo/thehub.wsgi
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        <Directory /media/rene/mybook/VSCode/Webvideo>
             WSGIProcessGroup flaskapp
             WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
             Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/flaskapp-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/flaskapp-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

thehub.wsgi (My WSGI on external hdd in folder with application.py)
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, "/media/rene/mybook/VSCode/Webvideo")

from application import app as application


Full Error message:
[Mon Apr 01 14:50:11.610517 2024] [core:error] [pid 115071] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:46760] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/media/rene/mybook') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path

I have tried:
find /media/rene/mybook -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find /media/rene/mybook -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

as well as:
chmod a+rX -R /media/rene/mybook

Any help is greatly appreciated as I am kinda stuck now :D
